# Does Anyone Know/Have A List of Caster Shells and Their Effects?

Tags: symbolism, outlaw-star

Got back into watching Outlaw Star, and always wondered about Caster Bullets and their numbering. Anyone got a complete list/set of the number. Do the numbers have meanings besides the bad luck shells?

Answer (score 1):

The numbers of the shells used in the show were 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 19, along with a shell that was unnumbered.

The Outlaw Star Wikia has a [nice page](http://outlawstar.wikia.com/wiki/Caster_shells) all about Caster shells.

> Caster shells are numbered by the wizards who create them. Their numbers appear to define the varied effects of each shell. Shells that are numbered #4, #9, and #13 are the rarest kinds, as they were only created by wizards of Tenrei, Ark Manaf, Hadul and Urt.[1](http://outlawstar.wikia.com/wiki/Caster_shells)

Most shells just draw on the mana stored within them, but those particular shells were special because they consumed some of the lifeforce of the user.